# Why Thread.sleep() from Service is not working?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

My code :

```
   callReader.speak("Incoming call from  "
                                        + contactName,

                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                                backNormalMode();
//                              try {
//                                  Thread.sleep(5000);
//                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                                  e.printStackTrace();
//                              }
                                callReader.speak("Incoming call from  "
                                        + contactName,

                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
//                              try {
//                                  Thread.sleep(5000);
//                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                                  e.printStackTrace();
//                              }

                                callReader.speak("Incoming call from  "
                                        + contactName,

                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

When Thread.sleep(5000)id kept in the above code, then Text to Speech speak doesn't works. But When Thread.sleep(5000) is kept commented, then it works successfully.

finally, i want that when once the time to speak finishs then it should sleep for 5 s and then again speak and then speak  then again 5s sleep.
why the above code is not working? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to call Thread.sleep() directly from a exposed method in the service.

The methods in the service are synchronous. 
1. Hence the sleep will make the UI wake longer than 5 seconds causing ANR
2. The service main thread sleeping can also cause ANR

You should never use Thread.sleep() from any main thread  - of UI or service. Spawn a worker thread and from that thread you will be able to use TTS + sleep + TTS

Edit 1 : added code snippet

```
public void foo(final Object a) {
    // This is your service method
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        // Put all your code here 
        <Text to speech code>
        Thread.sleep(5000); // this will work here
        <Text to speech code>
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Please paste code that you tried and did not work. It should. Also elaborate on what type of service this is and how you call the method